# How can I prove $\int_{0}^{1}\ln x\sqrt{(1-x^2)^{2n-1}}\,dx=-\frac{(2n-1)!!}{4(2n)!!}\pi[\psi(n+1)+\gamma+\ln(4)]$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Question:Prove that

$$\int_{0}^{1}\ln x\sqrt{(1-x^2)^{2n-1}}\,dx$$

$$=-\frac{(2n-1)!!}{4(2n)!!}\pi[\psi(n+1)+\gamma+\ln(4)]$$

where $\psi$ is the digamma function and $\gamma$ is Euler's constant.

This integral is used in many questions for a particular value of $n$ , which I was solving.It involves  combination of logarithmic and algebraic functions.

I have no idea how to prove this integral for $n$.

Can anybody help me to prove!
[image]

Comment: Start by letting $x^2=t$ then you get $\frac14 \int_0^1 \ln t \    t^{-1/2} (1-t)^{n-1/2} dt$, furthermore consider $\int_0^1 t^{a} (1-t)^{n-1/2} dt$, take a derivative w.r.t. $a$ and finally set $a$ to $-1/2$.